# Getting last match between brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Company 1 [CRM] - Hong Kong - [10003086] (57464)
Company 2  [SHP] Shanghai - [10003086] (12532)
```

I am trying to extract the second occurence between brackets from a string. What I tried:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(myid,CHARINDEX('(',myid)+1,(CHARINDEX(')',myid)-CHARINDEX('(',myid))-1) AS ID
FROM dbo.CRM
```

For the first record it returns the number I want '10003086'. For the second record it returns '[SHP]'. How to make sure the query always returns the last found result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
DECLARE @str     VARCHAR(100)= 'Company 1 [CRM] - Hong Kong - [10003086] (57464)',
        @fst_pos INT,
        @lst_pos INT

SELECT @fst_pos = Charindex('[', @str),
       @lst_pos = Charindex(']', @str)

SELECT Substring(@str, Charindex('[', @str, @fst_pos+1) + 1, Charindex(']', @str, @lst_pos + 1) - Charindex('[', @str, @fst_pos + 1) - 1)
```